# How to pass value between void Start() and void Update() in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to find out:

**how to pass the value assigned to a variable on Start() to Update() function?**

When I call the variable assigned on Start(), Debug.Log() on Update() shows null or nothing at all?

Comment: if the variable is declared in `Start()`, then it is not in scope inside of `Update()`

Comment: What should be the solution then? I load questions to a list on Start() and would like to access them in Update?

Comment: Declare the variable as a field in your script class. Then, you can assign to it in `Start()` and read it in `Update()`

Comment: Ah ok will try thank you!

Comment: Without wanting to be mean but if you have to ask this maybe before touching any code in unity you should get some [c# basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/) or in general about object oriented programming .. this is a very basic question.

Comment: I understood a field as a separate game object which will keep the value independently.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a more visual answer to the ones already stated in comments.

```
class MyClass 
{
    string hello;           // Declare variable

    void Start() 
    {
        hello = "world";    // Set variable
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(hello);   // Read variable
    }
}
```

Curly braces `{` & `}` define a *scope*, a variable declared in a scope will only be accessible in itself and child scopes (functions, etc, contained in that scope). So in our case, if you declare a variable in Start(), it will not be accessible in Update() since Update() is not inside of Start()'s *scope*.

Comment: no does not work this is my problem. I am using a list instead of a variable

Comment: @Yojimbo well we still can't see your code ...

Comment: A List can be stored in a variable; they are not the same thing. Please append your code, like @derHugo is suggesting, to your original post. We can't help you if you don't show us what you need help with.

Comment: But a few things on top of mind: 1) You're not instanciating the list with `= new List<Whatever>();` 2) You're overriding the list's content with a `public` accessor, which serializes the field and override code values with inspector values or 3) You're setting it from somewhere else, or you're not looking at the correct component.

Comment: @Yojimbo This does solve your problem. This is how it is done. He is showing you how to access a variable in two separate methods. If this doesn't explain the answer to you, it is clear that you need to take the most basic course in programming for any object oriented high level language at all. This is as basic as it gets. I do not mean to insult you. I am just being honest as it will solve a lot of questions you will have.

Comment: Also, "I am using a list instead of a variable". A list is a variable...